# Linq Where condition where there's possibility of a null reference

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, where-clause

So I'm working on converting a SQL Server stored procedure using Entity Framework. One of the queries I have to do involves a left join with a table that ends up being used in the where clause. (PS-Ignore the current select, I changed it around for debugging purposes)

```
    var union3 = (from o in orgs
                  from uos in accessOrgIds.Where(x => o.Id == x)
                  from sr in secRoles.Where(x => x.Id == secRoleId).DefaultIfEmpty()
                  where (o.StatusId == 1)
                  && (secRoleId == 0 || sr == null ? false : sr.Id == secRoleId)
                  select o);
```

`union3` has a resulting set of `o` whenever `sr` is removed from the where clause. How do I include the table in the query with the same effect as the following SQL?

```
    SELECT
        ISNULL(SR.Id, @securityRoleId),
        O.Id,
        O.Name AS OrganizationName,
        SR.Name AS SecurityRoleName,
        -1 AS IsSelected,
        SR.[Description],
        SR.IsSystem,
        SR.IsOATI,
        ISNULL(SR.StatusId, 1) AS StatusId,
        SR.IsAdmin
    FROM 
        Organizations O WITH (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN @userOrganizations UOS ON UOS.OrganizationId = O.Id
        LEFT JOIN SecurityRoles SR WITH (NOLOCK) ON SR.Id = @securityRoleId
    WHERE O.StatusId = 1
    AND (@securityRoleId = 0 OR SR.Id = @securityRoleId)
```

PS - `@userOrganizations` is a table used further up the stored procedure, which is working correctly

Answer (score 0):

You can try as shown below.

```
var union3 = (from o in orgs
              join uos in userOrganizations on uos.OrganizationId equals o.Id
              join sr in SecurityRoles on o.secRoleId equals sr.Id into gj
              from subsr in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
              where (o.StatusId == 1)
                  && (o.secRoleId == 0 || sr.Id == o.secRoleId)
                  select o);
```

Here you can find out about the [**Perform Left Outer Joins**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).